# Uploading a csv file in Cypress

Tags: csv, file-upload, cypress, ui-automation

I am having issues with uploading a csv file to test in cypress
so I am successful in uploading the file and clicking the submit button but the fields do not upload with new information which is in the csv.

```js
cy.fixture('contentData.csv').then((fileContent) => {
  cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
    fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
    fileName: 'contentData.csv',
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
  });
});
```

I was hoping someone can tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see a reason why you need to use `toString()` function. Try this:

```js
cy
  .fixture('contentData.csv')
  .then(fileContent => {
  cy
    .get('input[type="file"]')
    .attachFile({
      fileContent,
      fileName: 'contentData.csv',
      mimeType: 'text/csv',
  });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question but unfortunately it still not working.  The file is uploading but the values are not updated after clicking the submit button to the required fields

Comment: Perhaps it's not about the file upload, but some other feature. You mention some fields, but I thought we're talking about file upload only. Perhaps update your question, I don't know if I understand the context well.